# Possible to have prefilled value in input field highlighted

Tags: jquery

I'm searching, but I can't find if there are any options in jQuery to get the prefilled content in an input field to be selected with blue color. So far I just found how to use `focus` to get a flashing cursor.

I just want the user to be able to type in a new value without the need to first click inside the input field. When the user starts to type a new value, the prevoius value is erased from the input field.

```
$(".inputHours").focus();
```

Comment: can you share any example or something to be understand much easily

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can trigger the `select()` event before triggering focus.

> The `select` event is sent to an element when the user makes a text selection inside it. This event is limited to `<input type="text">` fields and `<textarea>` boxes.
>
> — [jQuery's `select()` documentation](https://api.jquery.com/select/).

```js
$(".inputHours").select().focus();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input class="inputHours" type="text" value="Hello, world!" />
```

Comment: I want it to be selected from the beginning when the page load. Is this possible?

Comment: @3D-kreativ wrap it in a `$(document).ready` function? https://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/document-ready

Comment: Thats not the problem! Perhaps you don't understand my question? You can click inside an input field and select the text, it gets blue. I want this to be selected without the need to click and select it by myself.(When I click inside your input field nothing happens, not in Firefox that I'm using right now)

Comment: @3D-kreativ hmm, looks like it doesn't work in Firefox (it works in Chrome and IE, which is strange). In Chrome and IE, as soon as you click "Run Code Snippet" it focusses the `input` element and highlights the "Hello, world!" text.

Comment: @3D-kreativ in regards to my above comment, it *does* work in Firefox. For some reason Firefox doesn't focus or select the text within the separate frame (Stack Overflow's code snippet window). The above code works fine in a raw JSFiddle demo: https://fiddle.jshell.net/ar6afpwy/1/show (here's the code: https://jsfiddle.net/ar6afpwy/1/).

Comment: Yes, it looks just the way I want it, but still don't work here! Could it be because I have the input field inside a div that just popup on a click event? It should work despite of that!?

Comment: @3D-kreativ you'll need to run the code when the popup opens, otherwise the `input` element will be hidden, unfocusable and unselectable.

Comment: So if I have som other code first that must run after the click, and then show the popup, it won't work!?

Comment: I tested to let the popup window be visible from the beginning, then it works. but when I close it and click to open it once again it's not working! Any ideas how to solve this?

Comment: @3D-kreativ you need to call it every time the popup window is opened.

Comment: I have tested that also! :(

Comment: Now it's working! Since I also used .val() to set a value to the input field, I moved the code after that line, and then it works perfect! Thanks for the help! :)

Answer (score 0):

You need to use $.select(); [jQuery select() docs](https://api.jquery.com/select/)

E.g.
If you wanted it to highlight all the text in the field on <strike>focus</strike> document ready, use this:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.inputHours').select();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input class="inputHours" value="Hello world">
```

Comment: I want it to be selected from the beginning when the page load. Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

This code for point your input box without click. I am little bit confuse for
pre filled content so if you have any  demo link then share with me.

```
    <input type="text" autofocus>
    <script>
        $(function() {
            $("[autofocus]").on("focus", function() {
                if (this.setSelectionRange) {
                    var len = this.value.length * 2;
                    this.setSelectionRange(len, len);
                } else {
                    this.value = this.value;
                }
                this.scrollTop = 999999;
            }).focus();
        });
    </script>
```

Comment: Hi, When you click inside a input field and select the text, the text gets a background color. I want that to be selected without me don't need to do anything.

Comment: it possible when you write something in input box first